# How can I add new logical partition?

Tags: partitioning

How can I add new logical partition?

I already have an extended partition, so I tried to use GParted to add a new logical partition.

1. I tried to resize the extended partition, but such an option is not available.
2. I tried to add a new logical partition but it only gave primary partition options.

Comment: Could you please show the output of fdisk -l /dev/sda (or whatever is the disk in question) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot resize the extended partition if any of the partitions on it are in use.

Boot into a LiveCD and use the GParted **without** mounting the partitions. Remember to make a backup before proceeding.

Comment: what should I use in liveCD menu?

Comment: Select your language, choose "Try" and wait a few seconds. If the desktop shows up, start GParted (it's called Disk Utility if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: No, Disk Utility is `palimpsest`. GParted should be called `Partition Editor` in the `System > Administration` menu.

Comment: Thanks, learned something today. Till now, I was in the assumption that Disk Utility = GParted.

Comment: the problem if I cant reboot computer like if computer server, should be another way

Comment: In that case, you're out of luck unless you're using something like [LVM](http://serverfault.com/q/38542/51929). Messing with partitions while the system is running is a *bad* idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a live-cd it could happen that it automatically mounts your swap partition. If your swap partition is inside the extended partition, you have to unmount it, before you can resize the extended partition.
By resizing you can add free space to your extended partition and afterwards create new logical partitions inside that free space.